# What is wrong with this SELECT query? No errors, no results

Tags: mysql, select

Haunted by this MySQL query that refuses to return results:

```
select entity_id
from customer_entity 
where entity_id NOT IN (SELECT sfo.customer_id
                        FROM sales_flat_order sfo);
```

If you divide the two statements they work independently:

```
select entity_id from customer_entity;
```

would return... 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

and

```
select sfo.customer_id FROM sales_flat_order sfo;
```

would return.... 1, 1, 2, 5, 6

Returning the same data type - INTEGER(10) - and many of the same values.

I'm assuming the problem might have something to do with the two columns not having the same name but I'm uncertain at this point.

**More information:** *There are indeed many null orders. The sales_flat_order table contains only 45 days of data whereas the customer_entity table contains 5 or 6 years of data. I'm trying to narrow down the customer_entity table to the 45 day period. The select query is just a precursor to the delete query I will be running.*

Comment: Can you include some example data and table describes?

Comment: It seems that all the records in your customer_entity table has an entity_id that exists as a customer_id in the sales_flat_order table. What are you trying to achieve as the output?

Comment: Did you try with NOT EXISTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there are records in `customer_entity` that have no related record in `sales_flat_order`, this should what you are looking for:

```
select 
    entity_id
from 
    customer_entity 
where 
    not exists (SELECT
                    1
                FROM 
                    sales_flat_order sfo
                WHERE 
                    sfo.customer_id = entity_id);
```

Answer (score -2):

Another way of writing your query would be by using the left join operator.

```
SELECT entity_id
FROM customer_entity 
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order sfo
ON entity_id = sfo.customer_id
WHERE entity_id IS NULL
```